# How to get time through assembly language interup

Tags: assembly

I write a code to print window clock through assembly in cmd but it give me a divide overflow error i need a help to find a mistake in my code and want correct code to print a window clock  in cmd........

```
             [org 0x0100]
                            jmp start
                             HR DB 0
                             MIN DB 0
                             SEC DB 0
                  printnum:  push bp
                             mov bp, sp
                             push es
                             push ax
                             push bx
                             push cx
                             push dx
                             push di
                             mov ax, 0xb800
                             mov es, ax 
                             mov ax, [bp+4] 
                             mov bx, 10 
                             mov cx, 0
               clrscr: 
                             push es
                             push ax
                             push di
                             mov ax, 0xb800
                             mov es, ax 
                             mov di, 0
              nextdigit:   
                             mov dx, 0 
                             div bx 
                             add dl, 0x30 
                             push dx 
                             inc cx 
                             cmp ax, 0 
                             jnz nextdigit 
                             mov di, 0 
                 nextpos:    pop dx 
                             mov dh, 0x07 
                             mov [es:di], dx 
                             add di, 2 
                             loop nextpos 
                             pop di
                             pop dx
                             pop cx
                             pop bx
                             pop ax
                             pop es
                             pop bp
                             ret 2

                 DISPLAY:

                             MOV DL, BH
                             ADD DL, 30H            
                             MOV AH, 02H
                             INT 21H
                             ADD DL, 30H    
                             MOV AH, 02H
                             INT 21H
                             RET
                    start: 
                             call clrscr 
                             call printnum

                             MOV DS, AX
                             MOV AH,2CH         
                             INT 21H
                             MOV AH, 09H
                             INT 21H
                             MOV DL, ':'            
                             MOV AH, 02H
                             INT 21H
                             MOV AL, MIN      
                             AAM     
                             MOV BX, AX
                             CALL DISPLAY           
                             MOV DL, ':'            
                             MOV AH, 02H
                             INT 21H
                             MOV AL, SEC    
                             AAM                   
                             MOV BX, AX
                             CALL DISPLAY           
                             MOV AH, 4CH
                             INT 21H
                             int 0x21
        This is the code when is use in nasm i give me error divide over please solve my problem.....
```

Comment: The first thing I see is 84 lines of code without a single comment. You are killing yourself by leaving them out. If you will add a short, descriptive, helpful comment to each line of code, you will realize a major advantage. Example: commenting the line `ADD DL, 30H`  would greatly improve your debugging by a large factor. Put a comment like this: `;This is to Make DL hold an Ascii digit now`  Do something like that for each line of code; tell the reader what and why you are doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly your program has more than A mistake!
Here are some problems:

The subroutines PRINTNUM and CLRSCR start promissing but then they're not continued! They even fall through into each other!

At the fifth line of the DISPLAY subroutine you need `mov dl,bl`

When calling PRINTNUM you would need at least some 16-bit value on the stack.

After retrieving the system time with DOS function 2Ch there is nothing to display with DOS function 09h. DX has binary info instead of an address!

Why do you end with 2 DOS interrupt calls in a row?

I think you'll want `mov al,[MIN]` and `mov al,[SEC]` instead of `mov al,MIN` and `mov al,SEC`.

Answer (score 0):

Note: For "MASM" it is only a cosmetic style between "mov al,MIN" & "mov al,[MIN]", but within brackets it is faster clear that "MIN" is not a constant for using as an immediate value, but rather a memory location, without to look in the constant and data declaration. So yes, it is recommended using brackets[] for to show the difference. And for using NASM the brackets are importend for a memory access.